# Can I use drupal view to create a "table of content" page for a series of pages?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-views

Say I am writing a manual for a product, and I have a series of pages named: 
"Chapter 1", "Section 1.1", "Section 1.2", "Chapter 2", "Section 2.1"

Can I use drupal view to generate a "table of content" page like this:

http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/

- Chapter 1

  - Section 1.1
  - Section 1.2
- Chapter 2

  - Section 2.1

or any module that can do this job?   thanks!

By using the "html list" format of "view" module, I can only get a list without hierarchy:

- Chapter 1
- Section 1.1
- Section 1.2
- Chapter 2
- Section 2.1

I am using drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the Book module that comes with core. You can see it in action with the [Drupal documentation](http://drupal.org/node/608152) pages; The structure that you need is in the block on the right. I expect that Views also provides some Book module integration. If not you can look at the code used to display the book menu block.

There are also a number of contributed modules that extend the Book module which are worth looking into.

Comment: seems that book module do not provide generating a table of content page for each single book. it only gives a Book navigation block and menu

Comment: The code that you want is in the block. Check book.module for the implementation and adapt it in your own module or block and display in a page.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of those who come searching, I include another option.

While Book module is indeed Drupal's answer to book structure, it does not handle everything (such as mobile page turning, custom TOC styles), and you may find it constrains you to patterns that don't quite fit.

A solution I have been looking into involves Views, Views Tree module, and References (or Relation) module.

While not very well documented, you can find it described here:
http://drupal.org/node/1493366

If I find a better alternative than that, I'll write it here.

UPDATE:
A good page for reference to alternatives to the book module:
http://groups.drupal.org/node/23899

I am currently trying out nodequeue with smartgueue_language to get a listing that is menu-like, translatable, and uncumbersome.